# Unique replacement for Excel.Range.Replace

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

How to replace the same occurrences in Excel with a different string?

The problem I have with `Excel.Range.Replace` is that the method replaces all occurrences in a single call. For example if I do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myNum; i++)
{
    myRange.Replace("foo", i.ToString());
}
```

Then all **"foo"** will be replaced with **0** instead of **1, 2 ,3 .**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void ReplaceFoosWithNumbers()
{
    int i;
    Range c;
    string firstAddress;

    Range rangeToSearchIn =  Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a5");
    Set c = rangeToSearchIn.Find("Foo", LookIn:=xlValues)
    if (c != null) 
    {
        firstAddress = c.Address
        while (true)
        {
            c.Value = i
            i = i + 1
            c = rangeToSearchIn.FindNext(c)
            if (c == null)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Please note that I wrote this code without a c# editor. It will require some corrections. Post comments, if you need any help.

Comment: What is the C# syntax for "With"?

Comment: @KMC: You can create a local variable (name it `range`) and then replace `.Find` and `.FindNext` with `range.Find` and `range.FindNext`.